# Invoke Object Quick Action from Enhanced Lightning Grid

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-quickaction, enhanced-lightning-grid

I am using a Salesforce Labs package: [Enhanced Lightning Grid](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EVK8iUAH), within the functionality is the ability to invoke standard lightning actions, for example:

`e.force:createRecord`

However, I would like to invoke one of my object-specific Quick Actions: "Send Email" (which normally appears inside of the `Activity Composure` component), so I would prefer for it to stay there if possible.

Any advice?
[image: quick-action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to invoke the Quick Actions API. This is a known limitation in the current package (version 3.36.0). See the issues log on Github here: https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/EnhancedLightningGrid/issues